# Tomcat website deployment error

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a tomcat website (octane generated) which I am trying to deploy on a devo box. The website loads up fine on my desktop. But when deploying on devo, it gives the following error in catalina.out log file :

WARNING: Error while removing context []

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:915)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1319)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1290)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:323)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1086)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1098)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:450)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:587)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook.run(Catalina.java:692)

Aug 4, 2011 12:06:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig undeployApps
WARNING: Error while removing context [/LiveWatchJvmPublisherWebapp]

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:915)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1319)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1290)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:323)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1086)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1098)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:450)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:587)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:648)
        at 

org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook.run(Catalina.java:692)

Aug 4, 2011 12:06:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Aug 4, 2011 12:06:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory ROOT
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /local/apollo/var/env/SCoMMockClientWebsite/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml (No such file or directory)

    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1013)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:964)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
    Aug 4, 2011 12:06:56 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
    INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-3080
    Aug 4, 2011 12:06:56 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
    INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-3043
    Aug 4, 2011 12:06:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 245 ms
```

It looks similar to this error http://www.coderanch.com/t/86776/Tomcat/tomcat, but I could not find a resolution after some digging around.

It would be great if you can throw some light on this, if it is a known issue.
FYI, I have not made any changes to the server.xml, context.xml files and web.xml.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just taking a wild stab in the dark here, but do you think this could have something to do with it:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /local/apollo/var/env/SCoMMockClientWebsite/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml (No such file or directory)
```